# Running sqlcmd on MAC m1 throws error "dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libodbc.2.dylib"

Tags: java, macos, installation, homebrew, sqlcmd

While trying to install SQLCMD library on macbook with apple silicon, I encounter the following error:

```
>brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
>brew update
>brew install mssql-tools
>sqlcmd

Output:
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/bin/sqlcmd
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      sqlcmd
```

I have tried reinstalling homebrew, sqlcmd, libtools and nothing has worked so far. I have also tried to brew unlink/link.

Any directions would be appreciated.